# Complete freezing - Ubuntu 20.04, probable problem with AMD driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, freeze, amdgpu

From time to time, my laptop unexpectedly decides: "It's time to FREEZE!". Then I cannot move my mouse or type. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> doesn't work, the clock in the upper bar stops, the screen is frozen. All I can do is to use power button and turn off the computer. I wouldn't say that this event is correlated with any sort of activity; of course, I mostly notice it during browsing the Internet, but I use the browser too often to distinguish any connections.

This time I've scanned all files of the computer with ClamAV and it froze again, therefore this is the problem I can force the computer to reproduce the error in order to diagnose it.

ClamAV scans all files in home directory without problems

Logs from this morning, when it froze **without** using ClamAV, just before freezing at 12:08

```
    Apr 29 12:07:51 user-Lenovo-Legion-5-15ARH05 kernel: [52106.947502] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 79, pid=32808, GPU has fallen off the bus.
    Apr 29 12:07:51 user-Lenovo-Legion-5-15ARH05 kernel: [52106.947505] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: GPU has fallen off the bus.
    Apr 29 12:07:51 user-Lenovo-Legion-5-15ARH05 kernel: [52106.947573] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: GPU is on Board
Apr 29 12:07:51 user-Lenovo-Legion-5-15ARH05 gnome-shell[15695]: [32808:32808:0429/120751.863519:ERROR:gpu_service_impl.cc(1177)] Exiting GPU process because some drivers can't recover from errors. GPU process will restart shortly.
```

When I run ClamAV on all files, I can see allocation memory errors when the second monitor is connected:[image: a photo, because I cannot do a printscreen]

Without the second monitor, the clamav reaches some point with scanning files (after allocation errors) [image: then the computer freezes.]

This is the output when I scan /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0: [image: another photo, because it freezes]

From syslogs I can see, that they are still written while the clock in the upper bar stops.

About the computer:

Ubuntu 20.04

Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 Ti

AMD Ryzen 7 4800H

I would appreciate your help, because I am stuck with solving the problem.

Output from `inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA driver: nvidia v: 450.119.03 
  Device-2: AMD Renoir driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: amdgpu,ati,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~120Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.119.03
```

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 0):

You should install the nvidia drivers from the Setup app. Do not try to install a version taken from someplace else.

The [Ubuntu Handbook](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/04/nvidia-430-09-gtx-1650-support/) describes the installation of the GeForce GTX 1650 Ti driver

But your picture shows data with "amdgpu". That driver should not be active, if you're using Nvidia. If you installed that GPU in **addition** to the nvidia driver, you must blacklist it in `/etc/modprobe.d`.

**UPDATE**

Your inxi shows that you have two GPUs. Either install the correct drivers for the AMD GPU (obviously you don't have them) or - if you do not need them - disable the AMD GPU, which is part of you processor...

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252153/amd-cpu-nvidia-gpu-on-a-fresh-ubuntu-20-04-system) is a thread concerning the AMD Renoir driver

Comment: Unfortunately, it failed. I have completed that tutorial. The errors are almost the same, but this time it won't scan further files and stops at memory allocation errors.

Comment: See my updated answer - that amdgpu driver should certainly not be on your system. Please add the output of `inxi -G` to your question

Comment: Thank you, @kanehekii. I've added the output of the suggested command to the question.

Comment: Updated my answer. You could've saved time if the data has been provided from the start...

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check it!